# Inverse of direct product of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have the question as to whether $Q(R×S)=Q(R)×Q(S)$, where $Q(R)$ is the total ring of fractions for a commutative ring $R$.

I think one should send any element $(a,b)/(r,s)$ to $(a/r,b/s)$, where $(a,b)\in R×S$, and $r$, $s$ are nonzero-divisors in $R$ and $ S$, respectively.

If the above argumemt works, I think that one could verify, by definition of the inverse of an ideal, that for any invertible ideals $A$ and $B$ in, respectively, $R$ and $S$, the equality $(A,B)^{-1}=(A^{-1},B^{-1})$ holds.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

So to show that two rings are equal, you need to construct an isomorphism between them. So let’s guess an isomorphism and see if it works.

$$ \phi (a/b,c/d) = (a,c)/(b,d) $$

Let’s check that this is well defined. Suppose $(a/b,c/d)=(w/x,y/z),$ that is, $ax=bw,\;cz =dy .$ So we need to check that $(a,c)/(b,d)=(w,y)/(x,z).$ This is equivalent to $(a,c)(x,z)=(w,y)(b,d)$ and so $\phi$ is well defined.

Now let’s check that it’s a ring homomorphism:
$$\phi((a/b,c/d)(w/x,y/z)) = \phi(aw/bx,cy/dz) = (aw,cy)/(bx,dz)$$
$$\phi(a/b,c/d)\phi(w/x,y/z) = ((a,c)/(b,d))((w,y)/(x,z)) = (aw,cy)/(bx,dz).$$
So multiplication works. We also need to check that $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ but I’ll leave that up to you for now and guess that it works. On the other hand, this is the bit that seems most likely to me to go wrong.